# how layout api version precedence works?

Tags: android

I was trying to implement different custom notification layouts for UrbanAirship push notification.

I had kept different version of `custom_notification_layout.xml` file in
**res/layout** & 
**res/layout-v8**

My intention was to change some text color if the OS version is **2.2 (8) & 2.3 (9)**.
I just tried for v8. In 2.2 device, it picks proper file from `layout-v8` but in 4.0 device it still picks layout from `layout-v8`.

How do i correct it ? and what is the problem here ?

Thanks

Comment: do you have a separate layout for 4.0 (layout-v15) ?

Comment: Sorry, i understood the problem. The `vX` indicates to look for matching layout file from that version and UP. So i created another folder for `layout-v11` to address for all higher version >9 and another folder `layout-v8` to address for version 8 & 9.

Comment: no problem, either delete your question or better - post your own answer and accept it